# Casting partial dates in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime, missing-data, to-date, str-to-date

I have a dataset that contains a birthdate attribute. The date format is `M/D/YYYY`(single digit representation such as 5/8/2009) and stored in text format. Now, I need to change the column type to date. But, there are many entities (more than that can be fixed manually) that have partial dates - that is, either day or both day and month are missing. For example:

```
"//1935"
"/5/1929"
"/4/1931"
```

Now, when I apply `to_date(birthdate,'DD/MM/YYYY')` I get error because Postgresql cannot parse these dates. What I need to do, is to fill in the missing values with a default value. For instance, `"//1935"` and `"/5/1929"` should be converted to `"1/1/1935"` and `"1/5/1929"` respectively. Is there a quick way of fixing this problem? Or, do I need to write a regular expression parser?

Comment: You need a parser. if start with `//` or if start with `/[0-9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a0d25/4)**

```
CREATE TABLE product
    ("inputDate" varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO product
    ("inputDate")
VALUES
    ('//1935'),
    ('/5/1929'),
    ('/4/1931')
;

SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN substr("inputDate", 1, 2) = '//' THEN '1/1/' || substr("inputDate", 3, 10)
            WHEN substr("inputDate", 1, 1) = '/' THEN '1/' || substr("inputDate", 2, 10)
            ELSE "inputDate"
       END as result
FROM Product;
```

Comment: great, thanks! Don't know why I couldn't come up with this simple and neat solution and instead was looking for regex parsing etc. :) @Juan Carlos Oropeza